# Mockito test for fluent wait selenium

Tags: java, selenium, mockito, testng

```
public void waitForFileDownload(int totalTimeoutInMillis, String filePath) {
    logger.info(String.format("Driver will wait for %s to be available withing %s milliseconds",
            filePath, totalTimeoutInMillis));

    String browserName = Configuration.getOption(Constants.Browser);

    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase(BrowserName.FIREFOX.getValue())) {
        filePath = filePath + ".part";
    }

    File fileToCheck = new File(filePath);

    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = getWebDriverFluentWait(totalTimeoutInMillis);

    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase(BrowserName.FIREFOX.getValue())) {
        FluentWait<WebDriver> waitForPartFile = getWebDriverFluentWait(5000);

        try {
            waitForPartFile.until((WebDriver wd) -> (fileToCheck.exists()));
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            logger.info(String.format("Could not find %s file in 5 seconds for firefox.", filePath));
        }
        wait.until((WebDriver wd) -> (!fileToCheck.exists()));
    } else {
        wait.until((WebDriver wd) -> fileToCheck.exists());
    }
}
```

I have below unit test however it is failing in else as file does not exist. I'm getting timeOutException. I use testNg.

```
@Test
public void waitForFileDownloadChromeTest() {
    System.setProperty("browserName","Chrome");
    Mockito.when(mockFile.getPath()).thenReturn(fileName);

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(mockDriver)
            .withTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Mockito.when(wait.until((WebDriver wd) -> mockFile.exists())).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.verify(new WebUtils(mockDriver).waitForFileDownload(1, mockFile.getPath());

}
```

How to mock wait.until((WebDriver wd) -> fileToCheck.exists());

Answer (score 0):

Try refactor your code for `waitForFileDownload` get `File` as argument.

Then mock argument:

```
Mockito.when(mockFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
```

and maybe other methods which are necessary.